# Can I install SAP Solution Manager in Ubuntu Server?

Tags: software-installation

I'm going to install SAP Solution Manager -- can I do this in Ubuntu Server?

Comment: This unanswered question is 5+ years old and OP hasn't signed on since posting question. This question has been abandoned and furthermore Ubuntu 12.04 server is EOL. VTC as `not reproducible`.